# How to use Haskell's `interact` linewise?

Tags: haskell, io

Solving some practise exercises I found 2 reoccuring IO patterns. The first pattern is already covered with the handy `interact`. The second pattern is similiar but processes the input linewise.

How to write an `interactLinewise` method?

Answer (score 5):

The most elegant solution I found so far is this oneliner:

```
interactLinewise f = interact $ unlines . map f . lines
```

Comment: Nice.  Btw those parentheses are redundant.

Comment: I would add spaces around `.`. That makes it a lot more obvious: `unlines . map f . lines`. And you probably want to add a type.

Comment: Some other useful standard functions for transformations like this: `words`, `unwords`, `intersperse`, `intercalate`, and `concatMap`.

Comment: Reminds me of [this old blog post](https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/156-Haskell_on_the_Command_Line) of mine.